How to add multiple fields in headers of a post api request
I'm new to SwiftUI and having trouble in sending a post API request, I want to add "User-Agent" field to my headers like this:

{"headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0
like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Mobile/15E148"}}

and here's my code:
       // Define the data to be sent
        let data: [String: String] = [
               "ad_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "device_id": "EE07C4CF-53CB-49D7-9991-111111111111",
               "device_token": "NOTFOUND"
           ]

        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(data)

        // Create the request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // Define the headers dictionary
        let headers: [String: String] = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        ]

        // Add the headers to the request
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        if let reqString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("paramater data: \(reqString)")
        }

But I'm getting 500 server error message in response:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Server Error (500)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>

Am I doing something wrong in my code, feel free to correct me

First off, I don't think this is an error related to SwiftUI, it's more Swift. With that being said, could it be some issue with your backend ?

Yes right, my backend is expecting data in encrypted form that's why I was getting 500 server error.
